# How to check if a folder is empty in remote MTF server from power shell script?

Tags: powershell, shell, sftp, mft

I want to check if a folder is empty or not in a MFT server. I want to do it with a .sh script. I have credentials to access the account service where the files are loaded. Not sure how to begin. Found out a solution but reads files not folders

```
echo "df myfile.txt" | sftp -b - example.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet.

Test-Path from Microsoft Docs:

> The Test-Path cmdlet determines whether all elements of the path exist. It returns $True if all elements exist and $False if any are missing. It can also tell whether the path syntax is valid and whether the path leads to a container or a terminal or leaf element. If the Path is whitespace an empty string, then $False is returned. If the Path is $null, array of $null or empty array, a non-terminating error is returned.

To make it easy, you can use `Invoke-Command` to run the command on a remote computer.

Invoke-Command from Microsoft Docs:

> The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer and returns all output from the commands, including errors. Using a single Invoke-Command command, you can run commands on multiple computers.

So you end up with something like this:

```
$exists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName [hostname of remote computer] -ScriptBlock {
      Test-Path -Path .\folder\*
}
if($exists -eq $true){
      echo "Folder is not empty"
}
else{echo "Folder is empty"}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.1